# Question about E-R modelling

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design

I've got the following business requirements for a scenario:

http://ompldr.org/vN2ZvdQ

and I came up with the following UML diagrams to model the relationship:

http://ompldr.org/vN2Y5Yg

I was wondering whether I have successfully managed to implement all the relations in the E-R model, especially the 1..* relationship. Furthermore, it is my understanding that mandatory relationships cannot be implemented just by using FK/PK so I have to add additional constraints, is that so?

Comment: If you post homework and don't identify it as homework, people don't appreciate it.  Also don't leave the link to your course notes up in the address bar in the background of your screenshots...

Comment: Just a tip, there are tools to model diagrams way nicer than Word. May be you want to take a look to [Visual Paradigm SDE for Eclipse](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/ec/) you can capture requirements, design databases, generate code, implement software and generate reports. SDE supports UML, entity relationship diagram and some more. Also there are different versions a good version is the Comunity one which is for free..!

Answer (score 1):

Its seems to be ok. You can use ERWin or [DBDesigner](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4) to doing your work in a easier way.
Consider `ON DELETE CASCADE, ON UPDATE CASCADE`, etc in your constraints.